# Update column with different value for multiple rows using a csv file

Tags: mysql, update

I often find myself using Excel to create update queries.

When I need to update multiple rows with different values for a column, I simply use Excel to create the update queries (multiple).

Here's an example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75f38/1).

If I have a list like:

```
Productname,Text
OpenIDM,testing
OpenAM,Tested
OpenDJ,great
```

I want to update the table with these values, so I need to create queries like this:

```
update ForgeRock set text = 'testing' where productname = 'OpenIDM';
update ForgeRock set text = 'Tested' where productname = 'OpenAM';
update ForgeRock set text = 'great' where productname = 'OpenDJ';
```

The format I receive the "To Be Updated" string in could be anything: Excel, csv, text.

The number of rows involved varies, depending on the project. Sometimes it could be just a few thousand rows, but other times it could be tens of thousands. I never timed myself or the time it takes to execute, but the execution time isn't really the problem. I just want an easier way to achieve this.

By "easier", I mean I should be able to update the table as mentioned without the need of Excel or a temporary table.

For example: to load data from a file it is possible to use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Have you considered exporting your Excel file to a CSV file, importing the CSV into a staging table in MySQL, then updating your target using a join to the staging table?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, I have considered it, but am looking for an easier way if there is. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Create some working space:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
    productname ...,
    text ...
);
-- copy all the .CSV into it:
LOAD DATA INFILE INTO t ... .csv ...;
-- do the Update en masse:
UPDATE ForgeRock
    JOIN t ON t.productname = ForgeRock.productname
    SET ForgeRock.text = t.text;
```

Assuming that nothing changes from run to run, exactly the same statements can be reused.

If you also need to insert "new" data, see IODKU.